# How to make spiral text in html using css or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, spiral

How do I make a Spiral Text using CSS or Javascript ?
check this image [image]

Comment: You should try something before asking for help.

Comment: We can help you debug your code, but you need to write some first. This being said, what you want to do looks very tricky.

Comment: There's no built-in way to this. You would have to calculate each letter's position and add / position them programmatically.

Comment: Have a look at this, you might be able to do it that way: https://css-tricks.com/set-text-on-a-circle/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Is it css, its it javascript? No its SVG

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 50" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <path id="MyPath"
          d="M 20,30 20,20 60,20 60,30 50,30"/>
  </defs>

  <use xlink:href="#MyPath" fill="none" stroke-width="0.1" stroke="black"  />

  <text font-family="Verdana" font-size="5">
    <textPath xlink:href="#MyPath">
      Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, 
    </textPath>
  </text>

</svg>
```

Comment: thanks to your idea, i already solve my problem using svg. you're right!

Comment: can you do this without using svg?

Comment: @KapitanTeemo you mean with css only? Well yes, you could. With Javascript? Yep also possible, but with a lot more coding.